# Dependence of answer on the length of inquiry

Tags: career-path

When contacting some scientist with a specific inquiry that goes beyond a simple research question, e.g. an inquiry concerning a specific career with a description of personal educational background and a request for advice - after all, it makes more sense to describe the personal situation instead of only asking "How does one end up doing ...?" -, what would be the limit of length of the inquiry where one should not expect an answer anymore?
One A4 page? Two ... ?

Comment: It depends a lot on your previous relationship with this person.  If you're emailing a total stranger asking for career advice, I expect the length limit is zero.